# Why does my python not add current working directory to the path?

Tags: python, python-import

I keep seeing sites mentioning that the directory that you execute 'python ' get added to the python path. For example on http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/understanding-imports-and-pythonpath, the author cd's to the /tmp folder then does 'print(sys.path)' and lo and behold, the /tmp folder appears in the path list. Here is me trying this out on my system (with 2.6.6 installed):

example structure:

```
app/
  mymodule.py
  inner_folder/
    myscript.py
```

in myscript.py contains the line:

```
import mymodule.py
```

what I did:

```
cd app
python inner_folder/myscript.py # ImportError
```

Since I am executing the interpreter from the app/ directory, shouldn't 'app' be added to the python path? This is how a lot of the docs I have been reading have specified the behaviour should be.

Please enlighten!

(I have temporarily solved this by manually adding the folder I want into the environment but don't want to rely on that forever. Since many sites say this can be done, I'd like to reproduce it for myself)

Comment: don't you mean : `import mymodule` instead of `import 'mymodule.py'
`.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

It is the *script's* directory that is added, not the current directory. If you turn `inner_folder/` into a package then you can use `python -m inner_folder.myscript` in order to run the script while having `app/` added to `sys.path`.

Comment: +1: indeed, even with the import fixed, this is the real solution.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I knew the script's directory was added but the only reason I believed that the "current directory" was added as well was because it used to work. I swear! Something  must have happened to make it stop working. I don't recall modifying the PYTHONPATH in any way so this is why I asked this question.

Comment: When running Python 2.7 in mac OS 10.7.5, the current directory is added for me, and the original example code works.

Comment: @CypressFrankenfeld, not sure why your current directory is added, but just for a sanity check, you might want to first execute `unset PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: @CypressFrankenfeld: in python versions prior to 3.4, an empty PYTHONPATH resulted in '.' being added to sys.path. See https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#changes-in-python-command-behavior

Answer (score 4):

Whether or not the current directory is in `sys.path`, import statements usually look like:

```
import mymodule
```

The code you wrote looks like:

```
import 'mymodule.py'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the module directory is not empty.  That may sound stupid, but in my case I hadn't realised that it was a git submodule and hadn't cloned recursively.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the cleanest solution is to add a `setup.py` like this structure:

```
app/
  __init__.py
  mymodule.py
  inner_folder/
    myscript.py
setup.py
```

And the content of `setup.py` looks like this:

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='my-app',
    version='0.1',
    packages=['app'],
    install_requires=[
          # a list of required packages if needed
      ],
)
```

After installing via `python setup.py develop`, in `myscript.py`, you can import mymodule like this:

```py
import app.mymodule
```

Or if you want to do `import mymodule`, you can move `setup.py` inside `app/`, same directory as `mymodule.py`, and change `packages=['app']` to `packages=[],`.

Comment: Note that for new projects, it is recommended to use `pyproject.toml` (or `setup.cfg`) instead of `setup.py`. See e.g. the note here: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html#setup-py