# python project structure and import

Tags: python, import

I got a problem with python projects. Here is my directory like:

```
Hotel/
    hotel/__init__.py
          a.py
          b.py
          c.py
    bin/run.py
    README
```

The whole idea is that I want to write a package hotel, and then I'll write some scripts(run.py) to use that package. So I put

```
from hotel import a
```

in to the file run.py.

But however, when I tried to run the run.py file under the directory Hotel with the command:

```
python ./bin/run.py
```

There is an import error saying: no module named hotel. 
But when I use ipython under this directory and when I type

```
from hotel import a
```

it works well. I don't know when I am wrong. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416424/why-does-my-python-not-add-current-working-directory-to-the-path), it does not matter from where you run `run.py`, it will be the scripts directory that will be added to the `PYTHONPATH`.

In python2.7 you will run into problems in any case if you do not put `__init__.py` files in the `Hotel` folder as well as the `bin` folder because you will not be able to execute them should you place the `Hotel` folder somewhere on your machine's `PYTHONPATH`.

You have two choices:

1) Put the package on the `PYTHONPATH` manually:

**bin/run.py:**

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'..')
from hotel import a
```

2) Move out run.py to the parent directory:

```
Hotel/
    __init__.py  
    hotel/__init__.py
          a.py
          b.py
          c.py
    run.py
    README
```

Comment: Thanks, for method 1 I think it's OK, for method 2 I have never seen people do like this, in every github repository there is no .py in the project folder..

Answer (score 0):

So hotel is a module for you. In order to be able to import it, you have to have the following in your python path: `.../Hotel` where ... is the full path to your Hotel directory. Try `import sys; print sys.path` to check it out.