# Python unexpected import locations

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

**Small context:** I'm writing a project in Python that uses Celery. I use a general framework of utility functions(that I wrote myself) that gets pip installed as a local module, the utility library is also used in other projects.

I have a project directory like this:

```
project/
  __init__.py
  celery.py
  test_runner.py
  some_more_files_that_dont_matter_for_this_example.py
```

And a utility project that I install as a python module that's like this:

```
__init__.py
utils/
  __init__.py
  utils.py
setup.py
```

Now, I have some code to initialize celery in the `celery.py`, this includes `from utils.utils import Utils`. The `test_runner.py` looks like this:

```
from utils.utils import Utils
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 1+1
```

And my `utils.py` has the following import in it: `from celery import Celery` which SHOULD refer to the celery module I installed with `pip install celery`.

Now what goes wrong when I do `python test_runner.py` is that it tries to import `utils.py`, which then apperantly imports `project/celery.py`(not the celery module I pip-installed) and that makes a circular dependency happen(since `project/celery.py` imports `utils/utils.py` as well).

Can someone explain to me how to make sure the `from celery import Celery`  in `utils/utils.py` only imports the actualy pip-installed celery module, and more importantly: why the imports happen like this? I'm running Python 3.5 and I thought that it would only do these local imports if I used `from . import x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python interpreter adds the script's directory to `sys.path` ([sort of reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6416470/3005167)). Furthermore, it is put at the beginning of the path and therefore searched first. This is why the local `celery.py` overrides the installed module.

You could either change `sys.path` and remove the local directory or put it at the back, but I think the better solution is not to name your local modules after global ones.

The `from . import xyz` syntax applies only to importing subpackages within packages ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references))

Comment: Hmm. I find it weird that in my local project I can't name my files after any packages the packages I use might (eventually) depend on, but at least I know now what is happening. Thanks