# Can't import from a file that is in the same directory

Tags: python, file, import, python-import, importerror

I can't import from a file that is in the same directory.

```
import unittest
from test_file import Rock
```

the `import unittest` works but the `from test_file import Rock` shows up as Import "test_file" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports on VsCode.

I tried the adding the dot before the test_file but does not work either
`from .test_file import Rock`

This happened after I updated my MacBook to the newest macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think that the answer to this question will solve your issue: [Why does my python not add current working directory to the path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416424/why-does-my-python-not-add-current-working-directory-to-the-path)

to summarize: python doesn't add your directory to PYTHONPATH by default. You can either set it in your environment, or you can:

- Create a package from your code
- Install it using `pip -e <path>`
- Use relative import (`from .test_file import Rock`)
- Call your code using `python -m <package>[.<subpackages>].<module>`